# Choosing between "while seeing" and "when I saw"

Tags: sentence-construction, gerunds

> A) I was quivering while seeing the horror movie.
>   B) I was quivering when I saw the horror movie.

Which out of the two is grammatically correct?
 Is it correct if we use two ing-form of the verbs ( quivering and seeing) in the same sentence?

Answer (score 1):

> I was shaking with fear while watching the horror movie.
>
> I was shaking with fear when I watched the horror movie.
>
> I shook with fear while I watched the horror movie.
>
> I shook with fear while I was watching the horror movie.

All are grammatical.

Because **shake** and **watch** both express an action which occurs over a time span, the continuous/progressive form (-ing) is not necessary, although its use does reinforce the idea of ongoing action.

Answer (score 0):

I was quivering while watching the horror movie.

I was quivering when I saw the horror movie.

Both the sentences are grammatical, but they don't convey the same mesning.

The former sentence expresses that both the actions of quivering and watching were ongoing simultaneously.  I was quivering while watching .... = I was quivering while I was watching.....

The latter sentence implies that after the first action of watching the movie was over, the second action of quivering was happening.  The conjunction when in the sentence means "after".  So "I was quivering when I saw the horror movie = I was quivering after I saw the horror movie".